# Embed new action in Yammer

Tags: yammer

I checked all the Yammer developer documentation, I cannot find anyway to add a new action inside Yammer, integrated with another Yammer APP similar to the recognize button action in Yammer for Recognize APP (check image below).

[image]

Please let me know from where to start if you have any idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Recognize site](https://recognizeapp.com/yammer-integration), the addition of actions to the Yammer publisher is done through Recognize's browser extension and not through any Yammer platform API.